# When I change a button's background attribute the ripple effect goes away

Tags: android, button

I change the background using

```
android:background="@color/button_color"
```

I like it because it gives the button a flatter look and because I can change the color to attract the user's attention. The only problem is it doesn't have that "ripple" effect when you press and hold or tap. I'd like to still be able to use a default `button`.

Comment: are you trying on a lolipop device?

Comment: try android:backgroundTint="@color/button_color"

Comment: @bhargav that works, although the buttons now have rounded edges rather than being square. But I can live with it, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should reference [this link.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/RippleDrawable.html) So that instead of giving pure color to your background, you should use a drawable with wrapped with ripple.

You can create a drawable resource like this and lets give it a name that "my_ripple_background".

```
 <ripple android:color="#ff00ff00">
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/black" />
 </ripple>
```

and in your layout xml, you should use it like

`android:background="@drawable/my_ripple_background`

Critical point is ripple is only supported for upper than 5.X versions. You should create your spesific drawable-v21 folder and place in it.

Hope it helps.

Comment: That seems to make the background of my buttons invisible. Any idea why?

Comment: Maybe we should define drawable instead of color given in item drawable

Comment: Figured it out, the autogenned xml started with a selector tag that I thought was necessary. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
android:backgroundTint="@color/button_color"
```

Comment: Upvoted for answering my question, but the other answer allows me to keep original functionality. Thanks anyway!